# How to automate property generation for a class in phpstorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm, auto-generate

If I implement a class, which gets some services injected, I have to write this bulk of code:

```
<?php
namespace Hn\AssetDbBundle\Services;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

/**
 * Class SomeNewService
 * @package Hn\AssetDbBundle\Services
 */

class SomeNewService {
    /**
     * @var TwigEngine
     */
    private $engine;
    /**
     * @var KernelInterface
     */
    private $kernel;
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(TwigEngine $engine, KernelInterface $kernel, LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->engine = $engine;
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
}
```

This seems redundant. Is there a way I can reduce the amount of code I have to write? Is there a live template for initializing the fields or can I autogenerate the bulk of this block otherwise?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the `Initialize field` feature.

This way, you only have to write the constructor method this way:

```
class SomeNewService {
    public function __construct(TwigEngine $engine, KernelInterface $kernel, LoggerInterface $logger) {        
    }
}
```

Then you can use initialize fields. Get the cursor over one property of the constructor, then on MacOS use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It looks something like this:

[image: Initalize fields feature]

After you press enter you are confronted with a list of properties, which you can select by <kbd>Shift</kbd> and arrow keys. By selection all the properties, your code will look like this:

```
    class SomeNewService {
    /**
     * @var TwigEngine
     */
    private $engine;
    /**
     * @var KernelInterface
     */
    private $kernel;
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @param TwigEngine $engine
     * @param KernelInterface $kernel
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(TwigEngine $engine, KernelInterface $kernel, LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->engine = $engine;
        $this->kernel = $kernel;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there no way to initialize the fields as protected or public?

Comment: @hackel I've been looking for a way to make them protected by default as well. Generally speaking both `public` and `private` are considered to be bad practice. Haven't found a solution yet though.

Comment: @Maurice from when private is considered as bad practice. 
Using public and protected is bad practice, because you don't encapsulate your properties.

You will find protected really bad when doing open source. People will use the properties in way it wasn't created for. 
Protected should be only used when really needed and public never.

Comment: Agreed. You should keep everything private in 95% of cases. You get stuff out of your objects using your methods. You generally only put stuff into your objects using your constructor. Think this way and you'll go far.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do the other way around, defining the properties first, and then in the "Generate" menu (Cmd+N), use "Constructor".

Comment: One of the things that confuses me most is that phpstorm calls Class member variables "fields" and not "properties" as is custom in php nomenclature. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 0):

On Windows :
put the cursor on the arguemnt of your construct method ,
then press Alt + Enter , hover/selct over initialize field , then press
Alt + Enter , then select field & press Ok .

Enjoy