# How to declare multiple fields in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have declare a lot of properties inside a constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->foo = new Foo();
    $this->poit = new Poit();
    $this->narf = new Narf();
}
```

Now I want to declare all fields, yet I only seem to be able to do so one by one via <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> "Declare field" on one property.

How can I declare all the fields? At best with the proper PHPDoc, as the when I use the declare field, only the property is added yet without any typehint.

It should be similar to [initializing all fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26165689/457268) yet I avoid injecting those services on purpose for that class.

I tried activating the "undefined field" intention, yet it is not listed:

[image: list of php intentions for field]

Answer (score 1):

After you press Alt+Enter, highlight Add field, press Right Arrow and select Fix all 'Undefined field' problems in file:

[image]

You will be prompted for the visibility of each field separately.

**Note:** In PhpStorm 2016.2.2, you'll have to disable "Declare field" intention and enable "Undefined field" inspection with "Notify about dynamic field declaration" checked.

Intention (Settings -> Editor -> Intentions):

[image]

Inspection (Settings -> Editor -> Inspections):

[image]

Comment: What version are you using? I'm on 2016.2.2 and I see neither `Add field` nor `fix all` in that context menu. I see "Add property" and "Declare field"; also not providing the option.

Comment: I'm using 2016.2.1, but I doubt the behavior is different in newer version. I'll upgrade and check again. Do you have "Undefined field" inspection enabled? Do you have `__set()` method in your class?

Comment: I upgraded my phpstorm and indeed it behaves differently. I edited my answer.

Comment: I also don't see that particular intention. Am I looking at the wrong place? See updated question.

Comment: And I also am unable to find: "Notify about dynamic field declaration", where is that hook?

Comment: Added screenshots to my answer.